# use joinpoint to trace user logout

Tags: security, spring, aop, logout

I'm using Spring AOP to make a system log,
my aop pointcut is like:

```
<aop:pointcut expression="execution(* a.b.*.service.impl.*.*(..)) or (execution       
(* a.core.service.impl.*.*(..)))" id="allMethod"/>
```

The problem is it only trace functions in service.impl,of course,if I change the pointcut,It can trace any service,or action, or dao,
But user's  logout,this project uses Spring Security,like "./j_logout",
not in any action, service, dao,so,I can't pointcut it,
is there any way to pointcut Spring Security so I can tell which user logout?
Any other solution without pointcuting Spring Security is fine too.
PS: English is not my first language,Do I make myself clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend`SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` and override onLogoutSuccess() then configure your filter

```
 <security:logout success-handler-ref="myCustomLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
```

don't forget to redirect to login page manually.

See documentation for any help.

Comment: I'm not quite understand,could you be more specific? Thanks a lot.

Comment: just extend SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler function onLogoutSuccess() is responsible for login page redirect. so if you override this function you can do inside it what ever you want.